# Use Fermat factorization to factor $809009\ldots$

Tags: number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

Use Fermat factorization to factor $809009\ldots$

So far I have:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{809009} & = 889.449 \\
& = 890 \\[6pt]
\sqrt{890^2 - 809009} & = 130\ldots ∉ \mathbb Z \\[6pt]
\sqrt{891^2 - 809009} & = 122\ldots ∉ \mathbb Z \\[6pt]
& \,\,\,\vdots \\[6pt]
\sqrt{899^2 - 809009} & = 28\ldots ∉ \mathbb Z
\end{align}

Ideally should equate to a whole number at some point, and according to my professor I shouldn't have to try for more than about 5 values. Not sure if I made an arithmetic mistake or just not using the formula correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $809009=823\times983$, so I'm not sure why your professor said 5 values is enough.

Comment: $\sqrt{809009} \approx 899.449$, you're starting early. Congruence considerations show that $m^2 - 809009$ can only be a square if $m \equiv 3,5,7 \pmod{10}$. That doesn't take you to trying only about five values, though.

Comment: @KennyLau Because the midpoint of $823$ and $983$ is $903$, which is very close to $\sqrt{809009}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  couple starting at $900$ with your observation and $903$ will be the first value tried.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, duh, I completely mis-thought. Forgot that you get $(u+v)\cdot(u-v)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{809009}=899.449$$

Your teacher is right. You can get it in about 5 values.

You should start from 900 rather than 890.

I have written some Python code to avoid doing manual work.

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_l8aZFH9i8fjEuMO.py

$$\sqrt{903^2-809009}=80$$

Hence the factors are $903-80=823$ and $903+80=983$